# Как устроен и работает предикат?

Tags: c++, stl

Не могу разобраться как устроен и работает предикат. Вот простенький пример использования предиката в сортировке:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool mySort(int x, int y){ // функция будет использоваться в качестве предиката
    return x < y;
}

int main (){
    vector<int> va;

    va.push_back(10);
    va.push_back(100);
    va.push_back(2);

    // for (vector<int>::iterator it = va.begin(); it != va.end(); it++)
        // cout << *it << endl;

    sort(va.begin(), va.end(), mySort); //третий параметр является предикатом

    // cout << endl;

    // for (vector<int>::iterator it = va.begin(); it != va.end(); it++)
        // cout << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

мне непонятно почему обычная функция рассматривается как предикат и почему в фунции-предиката два параметра, а не три к примеру и имеют целый тип параметров

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::sort` третьим параметром принимает что-то, что можно вызвать как функцию имеющую 2 параметра(полный список требований можно посмотреть [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare)). Не 3, не 1 — именно 2. Почему 2? Потому что для сортировки, за одну операцию, нужно сравнить именно 2 элемента.

Теперь касательно типа параметров: чтобы корректно сравнить 2 элемента массива, тип параметров функции должен быть совместим с типом элементов массива. Поэтому у Вас в коде и используется `int`. Но можете использовать и `long` и любой другой тип, который даст корректный результат сравнения. Но вот если Вы сделаете параметры функции, к примеру, типа `std::string`, то получите ошибку компиляции.

---

Для лучшего пониманию, предлагаю рассмотреть следующий пример:

```
#include <iostream>

void myFunc(int x, int y) 
{ 
    std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y:" << y << "\n";
}

template<typename Fun>
void superFunction(Fun fun)
{
    fun(156, 11);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    superFunction(myFunc);
}
```

Здесь, `superFunction` чем-то похожа на `std::sort`, она принимает своим аргументом что-то, что можно вызвать с двумя параметрами, причём каждый параметр является `int`. Внутри это «что-то» вызывается. Передав в функции `main` нашу `myFunc` мы получаем вызов оной, косвенно, через `superFunc`. Точно так же всё происходит в `std::sort`, только там переданная функция используется для сравнения двух элементов и в эту функцию передаются два члена массива, вместо констант, как в моём коде.

Comment: спасибо. ваш пример внес ясности

Answer (score 2):

Предикат в данном случае - функция сравнения, используемая алгоритмом сортировки. `std::sort` является шаблоном и компилятор подставит вызов функции-предиката при инстанцировании шаблона. Алгоритм будет менять порядок элементов коллекции основываясь на отношении (полного) порядка, которое и задаётся предикатом. Иными словами, для любых двух элементов коллекции предикат должен "сказать" который из них меньше.

В предикате два параметра потому, что алгоритм `std::sort` при работе сравнивает два элемента. Если использовать какой-либо хитронавороченный алгоритм, то ему может потребоваться и иное число параметров.

Тип `int` у аргументов предиката потому, что контейнер содержит элементы типа `int`. В общем случае типы не обязаны совпадать, а должны быть приводимыми. например, можно использовать предикат с аргументами типа `long` или `double`.

Кстати, вместо функций в качестве предикатов можно использовать лямбды (C++11):

```
std::sort(va.begin(), va.end(), [](const int x, const int y) {
    return x < y   
});
```